# Is it possible to make Angular.ui Bootstrap Dropdown drop UP?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular ui.bootstrap and I've had success creating a simple drop down menu, but when you put the menu at the bottom of the page, it goes off the page. Is there a way to make it open in the UP direction?

Thanks!
-fotoflo

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581352/how-to-get-a-bootstrap-dropdown-submenu-to-dropup

Answer (score 13):

you can use the dropup class with Angular UI Bootstrap like so:

```
 <div class="btn-group dropup" dropdown>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Bootstrap has a built in class for dropdowns called dropdown up!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just next to your dropdown class add dropup :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 is using this option by default.

[Here is the link for more information](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Comment: Please add the relevant piece of code or advice to the answer (in addition to the link). As links may change or not work in the future and make the answer incomplete.