# Dropup Bootstrap (v3.3.7) Toggle Menu when Fixed on Bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a bottom-fixed menu and want the toggle to dropup instead of down. I've tried all the solutions found in stackoverflow (like this one [How to get a Bootstrap dropdown submenu to 'dropup'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581352/how-to-get-a-bootstrap-dropdown-submenu-to-dropup)), wrapping up with .dropup class, or adding it to the element and so on, but nothing worked. This is my code:

**EDIT TO ADD URL:**
http://linares.kmturismo.com/

**EDIT 2 - TO POINT OUT THE ERRORS:**
One was the pointed out in the other answer. In addition,  I gave it `height: 50px;` via custom css class, which stopped the menu to dropup.

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linares de Mora</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#about">Que Hacer</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Alojamiento</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Historia</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Comida</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Más <span class="caret"></span></a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/edz80vw5/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linares de Mora</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about">Que Hacer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Alojamiento</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Historia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Comida</a></li>
          <li class="dropup">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Más <span class="caret"></span></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

The difference is made by the last **li** element of the first **ul** with class **dropup** instead of **dropdown**.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case it isn't working (changed the li class from the dom with developer tools): http://linaresdemora.kmturismo.com/

Comment: if you change the class through dom, it may not work because of js dependency, try adding in html. Not sure, it may work.

Comment: Done in localhost and also uploaded. Nothing.

Comment: Is your code picking bootstrap js? Just check if you have added jquery first and then bootstrap. This sequence matters. You can post if you are getting any error in console.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine and the order is ok. Thanks for your help @San.