# Bootstrap 4 dropdown submenu dropup variation

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 button dropdown. I want the dropdown menu to dropup. Using the dropup class as told here [How to get a Bootstrap dropdown submenu to 'dropup'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581352/how-to-get-a-bootstrap-dropdown-submenu-to-dropup), I somehow still cannot get the sub menu (Days and Hours in my code) to drop up.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropup">
    <button style="width:220px" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle    ml-auto" type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Period</button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu dropup multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" id="option2">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu others">Days
             <ul class="dropdown-menu bottom-up" id="days">
                <li class="dropdown-item option">1</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item option">2</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item option">3</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item option">4</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu others">Hours
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="hours">
              <li class="dropdown-item option">1</li>
              <li class="dropdown-item option">2</li>
              <li class="dropdown-item option">3</li>
              <li class="dropdown-item option">4</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    }
</style>
```

Thank you in advance for the help! :)

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've added the code for the submenu to work.

Comment: @ZimSystem, sorry I didn't get you. The submenu does work. But it drop downs while I want it to drop up.

Comment: It doesn't work in the code you've posted. The submenu doesn't appear at all. Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 4? Please post the code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Sorry I did not include the CSS earlier. I have edited my post now.

Comment: The problem is you're trying to use custom Bootstrap 3 code for submenus with Bootstrap 4. Dropdown positioning works differently in Bootstrap 4. There is no `pull-left` You should [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) to learn more about Dropdowns in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I thought nested drop downs do not work in Bootstrap 4 anymore.